# Jquery plugin (or custom) to mask fields to force users to enter valid email?

Tags: jquery, validation, email

I have seen a ton of jquery plugin to mask inputs, but none have anything available for email fields?

I have used http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ for phone and ssn. Anyone suggest a plugin for email fields?

Comment: I don't know that you can create a mask for an email address.. You're probably better off letting them enter what they want and then validating it as usual.

Answer (score 1):

You may checkout the [`jquery.validate`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin. It has the [`email`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/email-method) rule making it trivially easily to validate the input is an email address:

```
$('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
        field: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    }
});
```

An alternative approach if your client browsers support HTML5 is to simply use the [`email`](http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-input-types/#input-email) input type and you're gonna get the format validation for free.

But remember that no matter what wizardry you do on the client, you should absolutely validate the user input on your server. That's the first thing you should do before even thinking about doing any fancy validation on the client. Because that no matter how fancy validation rules you write on the client, people could always forge an HTTP request that's gonna directly hit your web server without going through any client side validation or javascript stuff.